# Wi-fi not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell, iwlwifi

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Inspiron 15 7537. It was working fine but after installing some updates (Not sure which ones) I rebooted and could no longer connect to wi-fi. It's a dual boot with Windows 8.1 and wi-fi works fine for that and Ubuntu does let me connect using a wired connection.

After reinstalling it's still giving me the issue which makes me think it's a hardware fault but the fact it works in Windows is making me doubt that.

One thing worth noting is that when I start Ubuntu it displays the following:

iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0z request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7200-7.ucode' failed
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0z no suitable firmware found!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this Solution


  http://askubuntu.com/questions/432053/how-to-enable-wifi-in-dell-5520-on-ubuntu-12-04-32-64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/egrumbach/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.

Comment: This has solved the issue, can't believe it was something so simple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @chili555 is that reinstalling the whole linux-firmare package won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall `linux-firmware` package by running,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

After installing it, reboot your pc.